# Will Gnome 2 aka "Ubuntu Classic Desktop" continue to be developed after 11.04?

Tags: unity, desktop-environments

In 11.04, if you don't want to use the new Unity desktop, you can use Ubuntu Classic Desktop (selectable from the login screen), which is similar to the Gnome 2 desktop provided in 10.10. Will Ubuntu Classic Desktop continue to be improved, or is it in "maintenance mode"? If the latter, will it continue to exist for the foreseeable future, or is the plan to eventually discontinue it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In the newest version of Ubuntu (11.10 Oneiric Ocelot), there will not be an option for "Classic Desktop" by default. The 'fallback' will likely be Unity 2D. [Source](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/739812/comments/5)

Gnome 2.32 is unlikely to receive additional official support. Gnome 3 (which is not the same as gnome shell) is available now, so any updates to the 2.x version will likely be small community fixes since 3.x will essentially replace it. Again, Gnome Shell is NOT necessary to run gnome 3.x, it is just a shell that runs on top of it.

Comment: Also I know this is old, but I thought it was worth clarifying.

Comment: updating questions is encouraged, regardless of age!

Answer (score 0):

AFFAIK Gnome2 will "stop" development at 2.30 (actually 2.32, my mistake). I think there will still be security updates. Most of Gnome developers is working at Gnome Shell (Gnome3).

Comment: I don't know what Ubuntu will do, but GNOME 2.32 was already released and is nominally the final community-supported version. However, the suspicion is that there will be a few distros that will want to ship and support GNOME 2.x for some time to come, so there *may* be one or two further (possibly off-cycle) bugfix releases, or each distro may just patch their own 2.x release as required.

Comment: Oh, sorry I confused the versions.

Answer (score 0):

GNOME 2.xx is officially superseded by GNOME 3.xx, but that doesn't mean the "classic" look is dead. In fact, the gnome-panel is still being developed, along with some applets, and everything else you know and love from GNOME 2.xx is simply improving with the rest of GNOME 3.xx.

In essence what I'm saying is, it will not die (is not dead) and will live on with 11.10 and others to come :), just not as part of the default install.